# block data flow from a TCP socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm using libsoccr, which allows to checkpoint/restore TCP connection. Here is how I'm trying to use it :

```
/* some code to initialize and connect the socket */

#define max 10000000
struct libsoccr_sk *so;
struct libsoccr_sk_data data;
int sockfd, dsize, size;
char *buff = (char *)malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));

/* some code to fill the buffer */

write(sockfd, buff, MAX);
so = libsoccr_pause(sockfd);
dsize = libsoccr_save(so, &data, sizeof(data));

/* some code */
```

The function `libsoccr_save(so, &data, sizeof(data))` returns me -6.

I re read libsoccr's documentation, and found out "any data flow for this socket must be blocked by the caller before this call" talking about `libsoccr_pause(sockfd)`. I looked into the source code and found out that the queue length is got with `ioctl(sockfd, SIOCOUTQ, &size)` and later, the content of the queue itself is got with `ret = recv(sockfd, buf, size+1, MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT)`. Using gdb, it appears that I always get `ret = 0` even if the queue is not empty, surely because I don't block the data flow of the socket, but I have no clue on how to do it.
So the question is, how can I block the data flow of a socket ?

Comment: where are you initializing sockfd ? Now it looks like you are writing to an uninitialised socket.

Comment: I didn't put the whole code, just the parts concerning my problem. The socket is initialized and connected. No problem on that, and the data is received correctly on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to block the data flow of a socket is to use "plug qdisc". All the documentation can be found here : [https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/api/group__qdisc__plug.html](https://www.infradead.org/%7Etgr/libnl/doc/api/group__qdisc__plug.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'll try. The plug qdisc can be used to 'stop' the flow of packets incoming (or outgoing) from a network interface. I guess this isn't the place to describe qdiscs in full but let's say you have one egress qdisc per interface (and you can add more, filtering on specific traffic if you want). If you put a plug qdisc on a specific packet stream, you can then (through netlink) stop (plug) the flow of packets (they'll be buffered until you unplug). Instead of throwing the packets away, you can keep them. If you need to put a ingress qdisc on a interface, the canonical way is to use an IFB.

Comment: The IFB will act like a 'virtual' interface-in-the-middle and you can add an egress plug qdisc to it. Armed with that you can, before you start saving the state of a tcp socket, ensure nothing from the outside stimulates you tcp socket (an ack for example) and then you can start saving all queues and states, then unplug and let the flow of packets continue as if nothing had happened.

Comment: What's happening to OP is that the queues of his tcp sockets are being updated between the ioctl ('get queue size') and the actual capture of the queue content. Probably because the other tcp participant has sent a packet in between that updated the socket state. The 'pause' command is actually badly named, as it only pauses the socket for userland and not the asynchronous updates in the kernel. It's recommended to 'filter out' (at least) the ingress traffic, but it's a bit painful if you *just* wanted to save the tcp socket state. Using the plug qdisc+ifb is actually the only solution I found